# Drupal: Auto fill CCK field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, cck, drupal-fields

I have a "movie" content type, on the node for a movie I have a link to create "Movie Review" content. I was wondering if it is possible to pull the title of the "Movie" Node and put it in the Title field of the "Movie Review" creation page when the link to create a new "Movie Review" is clicked from a specific movie?

For instance: if I am on a page with a node title of "Basic" when I click the link to write a review, it will automatically fill in the "Movie Review" title field with "Basic.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Entity Reference module for that.